# Take a character from a string and convert it to int in c

Tags: c, string

I'm new to c and trying to write a console application that takes the time signature and BPM information from a user's musical project and returns the length of one bar in seconds.

I want to take the user input string for time signature (example: "4/4"), isolate the first character (a numeral representing the number of beats per bar), and transform it into an integer to be used in the calculation.

The two methods I've tried,

```
int beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0];
```

and

```
int beatsPerBar = atoi(timeSignature[0])
```

both return the same error: "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".

How do I correctly change the variable type of this character?

EDIT:

Using @R-Sahu 's suggestion.  The code below compiles and builds with no errors or warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

   char timeSignature[4];
   int BPM;

   printf("Enter the working time signature of your project:");
   scanf("%s",&timeSignature[4]);

   int beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0]-'1';

   printf("Enter the beats per minute:");
   scanf("%i",&BPM);

   printf("%i\n", beatsPerBar);

   return 0;

}
```

However, when I test the code with the following values

```
timeSignature = "4/4"
    BPM = 180
```

I get a resulting integer of `-47` (calculator check says it should be returning `45`).

What am I doing wrong?  Clearly my understanding of encoding and the integers used to represent character values isn't where it should be.  Can anyone share links to broad tutorials on this subject?

Comment: They "return the error ..."? Unlikely. You mean you get a compiler error/warning. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, and you cannot change the type of a variable (not even in a dynamically typed language).

Comment: Don't forget funky time signatures like 10/8.

Answer (score 2):

Use of

```
int beatsPerBar = atoi(timeSignature[0])
```

should result in a compiler error. The input argument type of `atoi` is `char const*`, which `timeSignature[0]` is not.

```
int beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0];
```

is syntactically right but not semantically. That will set the value of `beatsPerBar` to the integer value used to represent the character `4`. If your platform uses ASCII encoding, that value is `52`.

You should use:

```
int beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0] - '0';
```

to get the number `4` assigned to `beatsPerBar`.

If you want to be more careful, which you should, you can add the following check.

```
int beatsPerBar = 0;
if ( isdigit(timeSignature[0]) )
{
   beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0] - '0';
}
else
{
   // Deal with error.
}
```

Comment: @NathanielLindsey, did you have a question there? BTW, `timeSignature[0]-'1'` is going to give you the wrong result.

Comment: See edits to my original question.  I couldn't condense enough to fit it in a comment.

Comment: @NathanielLindsey, `scanf("%s",&timeSignature[4]);` is not right. It passes the address of the last element of `timeSignagure` to `scanf`. You end up accessing the array out of bounds. Use `scanf("%s",&timeSignature[0]);`, or simply  `scanf("%s",timeSignature);`

Comment: I'm getting incorrect values as output, so I ran the following test with the same test values from my original question edit to confirm the integer value of 'timeSignature[0]':

int main()
{

   char timeSignature[4];

   printf("Enter the working time signature of your project:");
   scanf("%s",timeSignature);

   int beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0]-'0';

   printf("%i",beatsPerBar);

   return 0;

}

The return value is '3', not '4' like I need, but when I fail to subtract the '0' character, the return value becomes 52.  Again, what am I doing wrong? (and why isn't my code formatting showing?

Comment: @NathanielLindsey, you are getting `3` instead of `4` since you are using `timeSignature[0] - '1'`. That should be `timeSignature[0] - '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

As @r-sahu said:

> The input argument type of atoi is const char *

So if you still want to use atoi you can convert the char to a string then use atoi as follows (for example):

```
if (isdigit(timeSignature[0]))
  char dig[2]= {timeSignature[0],'\0'};
  int beatsPerBar = atoi(dig);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `atoi`, you can simply convert a `char` to `int`. For instance

```
int beatsPerBar = timeSignature[0] - '0';
```